# Why does Firefox often alert "A script on this page may be busy"?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox

It hangs my browser and sometime PC also.

> A script on this page may be busy, or
> it may have stopped responding. You
> can stop the script now, or you can continue
> to see if the script will complete.
>
> Script: chrome://browser/content/browser.js:9065

Is there anyway to get rid of this ?

[image]

Comment: Ok, are you talking about Chrome or Firefox.  The screenshot you have there clearly says chrome://browser....

Comment: Jpg image format is a bad choice for screenshots, see http://lbrandy.com/assets/jpg_vs_png2.png

Comment: @Daisetsu I can confirm this: The error message is displayed in Firefox but says "chrome://..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the error screenshot, it refers to an *internal* script "chrome://browser/content/browser.js". Hence, it's probably an addon you've got installed that's causing the problem.

Disable/uninstall all addons and then load the page to see if you still have the problem. Then enable/install them one by one until you find the one that causes the problem.

(If that doesn't help then there's some more instructions, such as starting in Safe Mode and using the default theme, at "[Troubleshooting extensions and themes](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Troubleshooting+extensions+and+themes)".)

Comment: @Metal, the script depends on the version of Firefox you're using. Typing "chrome://browser/content/browser.js" in your location bar (address bar) will give you the script. Paste it into an editor that shows line numbers. Copying the part around line 9065 into your question might help us figuring out what's the exact cause.

Comment: I don't need add-ons to have some Firefox' *internal* script give me this.

Answer (score -1):

Well, one way is to disable scripting.  For Firefox, install [NoScript](http://noscript.net), and you can enable scripting for sites you choose, but have it off as the default.

Comment: I wonder if it would actually help, as it does not seem to be a script on the website that is causing trouble. Apart from that, the web hardly can do without JavaScript nowadays.

Comment: @arjan, interesting, I didn't know that NoScript only blocked non-chrome scripts, but that makes sense now that I think about it.  As far as usability, that was the reason for suggesting NoScript.

Comment: The script running wild here is *an internal script*, *inside Firefox*. Firefox has a lot of JavaScript in himself, this is his kryptonite.